# How can I refactor these two lines to one statement?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
// TryGetAttributeValue returns string value or null if attribute not found
var attribute = element.TryGetAttributeValue("bgimage");

// Convert attribute to int if not null
if (attribute != null) BgImage = convert.ToInt32(attribute);
```

The thing I don't like is that I have to create a temp variable, `attribute`, in order to test if it's `null` or not, and then assign the value to the `BgImage` variable, **which is a nullable int**.

I was hoping I could figure out a way to write it all on one line, but I cannot figure a way.  I even tried using a ternary statement, but got nowhere:

```
if (element.TryGetAttributeValue("bgimage") != null) ? BgImage = //Convert result to int :  else null;
```

Realistically, my original two lines of code do the job.  I was just hoping to pare it down to one line.  But, if anyone knows how to do what I'm trying to accomplish, I'd love to learn how.

Comment: Are you parsing something like xml?

Comment: A `TryGetAttributeValueAsInt` extension?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Yes, I am.  The BgImage attribute can either be null, or an int, including zero.

Comment: @KevinJ and what value you want to have if attribute not exist?

Comment: @AlexK. I actually thought about doing that, but wanted to see if what I was trying to do was possible, before writing another extension method.  He, I may end up doing just that, if I can't find an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to use [Linq to Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943906.aspx) for parsing Xml (according to your attempt you have BgImage as nullable integer):

```
BgImage = (int?)element.Attribute("bgimage");
```

You also can assign some default value if BgImage is not nullable:

```
BgImage = (int?)element.Attribute("bgimage") ?? 0;
```

Comment: This worked fine for me.  I didn't have to use the "TryGetAttribute" method at all, and I got the results I was looking for.  I'll mark this as the answer as soon as the timer is up.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `TryGetAttributeValue` returns a `string` you could do something like

```
BgImage = convert.ToInt32(element.TryGetAttributeValue("bgimage") ?? "-1")
```

This would set `BgImage` to a default value (`-1`) if the attribute does not exist. If you would prefer to have `BgImage` set to `null` when there is no `bgimage` attribute then it gets a *little* bit clunkier

```
BgImage = element.TryGetAttributeValue("bgimage") != null ? 
    convert.ToInt32(element.TryGetAttributeValue("bgimage")) : (int?)null;
```

Comment: I assume `BgImage` should be null not -1 if the attribute is null.

Comment: `TryGetAttributeValue` returns a string if found, `null` if not found.  BgColor can be an int, including zero, or a `null` value.

Comment: @KevinJ so in the case where the attribute can't be found you would prefer to set `BgImage` to `null`?

Comment: @James That's correct.  The XML I'm parsing can either have `"bgcolor = "0"` or `"bgcolor" = some other int` or no `"bgcolor"` attribute at all.